# mod_cluster, virtual hosts, and jboss root context in JBoss EAP 6

Tags: jboss7.x

We're running Apache 2.2, mod_cluster 1.1, and JBoss EAP 6.0.1 (JBoss 7) on linux.

I'm trying to set up virtual hosts in JBoss without setting the virtual host in jboss-web.xml.  The goal is for http://my.example.com/ to route through apache/mod_cluster and serve the application running on the context root /.   The application runs fine in standalone mode.

The apache configuration:

```
LoadModule slotmem_module       modules/mod_slotmem.so
LoadModule proxy_cluster_module modules/mod_proxy_cluster.so
LoadModule advertise_module     modules/mod_advertise.so
LoadModule manager_module       modules/mod_manager.so

Listen 192.168.1.2:6666
<VirtualHost 192.168.1.2:6666>
    ManagerBalancerName mycluster
    ServerAdvertise On
    CreateBalancers 0
    ... other content snipped ...
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
       ServerAdmin my@email.address
       ProxyPass / balancer://mycluster stickysession=JSESSIONID|jsessionid nofailover=On
       ProxyPassReverse / balancer://mycluster
       ProxyPreserveHost On
       ServerName my.example.com
</VirtualHost>
```

The application has this content for jboss-web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<jboss-web>
    <context-root>/</context-root>
</jboss-web>
```

The profile used by the server where the application is deployed is configured thusly:

```
<virtual-server name="default-host" enable-welcome-root="false" default-web-module="my-app-name">
    <alias name="my.example.com"/>
</virtual-server>
```

And we have an app with a war file named my-app-name.war.  (I have tried this with and without default-web-module provided, with the same result)

When I start jboss on the application servers, they appear to start the application without a problem:

```
[Server:MyApp] 12:17:34,786 INFO  [org.jboss.web] (MSC service thread 1-3)
JBAS018210: Registering web context:
[Server:MyApp] 12:17:34,811 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread)
JBAS018559: Deployed "my-app-name.war"
[Server:MyApp] 12:17:34,823 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015874:
JBoss EAP 6.0.1.GA (AS 7.1.3.Final-redhat-4) started in 35274ms - Started 502 of 649
services (146 services are passive or on-demand)
[Host Controller] 12:17:34,829 INFO  [org.jboss.as.host.controller] (proxy-threads -
1) JBAS010919: Registering server MyApp
```

When I try to go to http://my.example.com, I get the apache error:

```
proxy: CLUSTER: (balancer://mycluster). All workers are in error state
```

When I inspect /mod_cluster-manager on the webserver, I do not see the context root for / defined.  I do, however, see the context root defined by another app in the same cluster, which is using a different profile:

```
context: 1 [/OtherApp] vhost: 1 node: 3 status: 1
context: 2 [/OtherApp] vhost: 1 node: 2 status: 1
```

The other application runs fine on http://mydefaulthost.com/OtherApp.

Comment: This seems to be a mod_cluster or virtual hosts issue since accessing the application directly on the application server works on the context root.

Answer (score 2):

there is a configuration absent on yours

REMOVE the ROOT context from the list above

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:modcluster:1.1">
    <mod-cluster-config advertise-socket="modcluster" excluded-contexts="ROOT,invoker,jbossws,juddi,console" proxy-list="192.168.0.62:6666" connector="ajp">
        <dynamic-load-provider>
            <load-metric type="busyness"/>
        </dynamic-load-provider>
    </mod-cluster-config>
</subsystem>
```